# How to open a dat files from a vcd?

Tags: vcd

I am trying to open .dat files from a vcd but can not open them. Help please?

Answer (score 1):

Install open the terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

then open with movie player(totem)

Or install **vlc** media-player

```
sudo apt-get-install vlc
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The .dat file on VCDs cannot be opened directly on Linux as its a so-called "gateway" file. You can open such files using *vlc* and *mplayer* on Linux.

To open with mplayer,

```
$ sudo apt-get install mplayer 
$ mplayer vcd://<track> [-cdrom-device <device>]
```

Examples:

To play VCD track #1,

```
$ mplayer vcd://1
```

To play VCD track #1 when disk is not detected,

```
$ mplayer vcd://1 -cdrom-device /dev/sr0
```

To play with VLC, follow the earlier answer to install VLC and then.

```
$ vlc vcd://<device>
```

Example,

```
$ vlc vcd:///dev/sr0
```